# Bootstrap 4: fix contents bottom inside container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an app wrapped around a `<div class="container">`, in which I have an editor and a few buttons, which I always want to be shown at the bottom, something like so:

```html
<div class="container>
  // some content....


  // this should be shown always at the bottom!
  <div id="bottom" class="submit-form">
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <div class="btn btn-grp" ></div>
  </div>
```

I have tried changing the min-height, and height properties of html, body and container to be 100% and added important to this rules, but that doesnt make my div container stretch any more downwards. When I use the "fixed-bottom" bootstrap class, the #bottom div stretches horizontally over the container boundaries, which makes the layout completely ugly.

any suggestions? :)

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible problem. Add CSS code so that we can test it.

Comment: can you added your full basic code or fiddle

Comment: bottom of the container or bottom of screen regardless the height of the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your "submit-form" with another container or use `col-*` for positioning.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- some content.... -->


  <!-- this should be shown always at the bottom! -->
  <div id="bottom" class="container fixed-bottom submit-form">
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <div class="btn btn-grp" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Manipulate your div size by `col-*` class (bootstrap grid contains 12 columns, so below  div will cover 4 columns of screen size)  :

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- some content.... -->


  <!-- this should be shown always at the bottom! -->
  <div id="bottom" class="col-4 fixed-bottom submit-form">
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <div class="btn btn-grp" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After that this form will be aligned to the left side of the screen.

Use d-flex for positioning your bootstrap column:

```
  <div class="container">
      <!-- some content.... -->
    
    
      <!-- this should be shown always at the bottom! -->
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-center fixed-bottom">
        <div id="bottom" class="col-4 submit-form">
         <div id="editor"></div>
        <div class="btn btn-grp" ></div>
  </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

If you want to create responsive web site, you should read something about bootstrap grid system and use `col-md-*`, `col-sm-*` etc. instead of `col-*`:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: this helped me a lot. It ended up being not exaclty that what I needed, but pushed me into the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad that i could help. If you have any other solution, please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the BS4, then there is lots of classes provided by BS, use those to achieve your output.

I have added some height to row, just to show you desired result, As we will have some content in container then you would not need any height on row.

**NOTE**: If you do not want to use row, just in case, then use class `d-flex` on container and rest will remain same.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="height: 200px;">
<div id="bottom" class="submit-form align-self-end">
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <div class="btn btn-grp" >Button</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```